# One strange issue about $.load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, load

This is the file I'm using $.load() to load into DOM:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.close').click(function() { alert(1) });
</script>
<div class="close">
    click me
</div>
```

Say,it seems to me that the `<script>`  part will automatically be delayed when it's **loaded** ,is that a feature of $.load()?

If so,how is that implemented?

Feels amazing!

Comment: How do you mean delayed?  Do you mean to say that the alert doesn't happen when $.load() is called, but instead happens only after this action and the DIV has been clicked?

Comment: The script won't work as expected if you access the file directly with a browser(when clicking to it,no alert).But if you loaded it to another page with $.load(),it will work(alert when you click).

Comment: This is probably because loading it directly doesn't give the DOM any time to be ready before trying to bind that event. But using load, it gives the DOM time to load and be ready before binding.

Comment: Is this the only HTML in the page that is loaded into DOM?

Comment: Has anyone ever successfully dive into source of jQuery to see what happened exactly?

Comment: Check my answer. Took me half an hour to find, but yes!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've read through the jQuery source, and here's what I've found:

*(line numbers reference the uncompressed jQuery 1.3.2)*

1. `jQuery.load` ultimately gets the response and calls the jQuery `html` method with the result to insert it. *(around line 3267)*
2. `jQuery.html` then calls the jQuery `append` method. *(line 488)*
3. `jQuery.append` then calls the `domManip` method with a callback function that inserts the DOM nodes. *(line 253)*
4. `domManip` *(at line 514)* is a little tricky, but ultimately it does in fact pass the DOM nodes to the callback to be inserted, then calls `evalScript` for each script **after** inserting the DOM nodes, regardless of their order in the html that was loaded. *(line 526)*.

Hence, jQuery does in fact execute the scripts in a delayed fashion!

*use the source, Luke.*

Answer (score 0):

"The script won't work as expected if you access the file directly with a browser(when clicking to it,no alert).But if you loaded it to another page with $.load(),it will work(alert when you click). – Shore"

When you load the file in browser as itself, the reason why there's no alert when you click it is because when the browser reads the line "`$('.close')...`", there's no DOM object of class "`close`" yet, because the  comes after the script tag.

You can resolve this by:

```
$(document).ready(function(){$('.close').click(function() { alert(1) });});
```

As for the delay part, it is because that when you use $.load(), the function loads the file first, then put the source into the DOM object. After putting source into the DOM object, it will then parse the `<script>` tags in your file. That's why your click event is binded successfully to your DOM objects with class `close`

Comment: After putting source into the DOM object, it will then parse the <script> tags in your file. 

Did you say it according to jQuery source code?

Comment: that's what the logic should be. getting file source via ajax, put into dom, then parse for script.